# AutocompleteTextView filled with Google Search results

Tags: android, search, autocomplete, textview

I need to have a TextView that, when the user type in it a word, a dropdown list box is be shown exactly with the same phrases that Google Search will suggest if those words are typed in the search textbox of google.com site.

Is it possible to have this service. How?
I searched on the web with no luck.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

For the dropdown you can use:

[Autocomplete Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

For show result you must call your own web service or cached data. If you need google results i don't know if google expose a public API to obtain it...

Answer (score 0):

Hi Geltrude here i added the sample source code for you. Please try and let me know. Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks.

First create **autocomplete_textview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Search Name"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    android:singleLine="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

**AutocompleteSample.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

public class AutocompleteSample extends Activity {
    private static AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.autocomplete_textview);        
    autoCompleteText = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteText);
    List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    nameList.add("Steve");
        nameList.add("Bill");
        nameList.add("Tom");
        nameList.add("Arnold");
        nameList.add("Vishva");
        nameList.add("Durai");
        nameList.add("John");
        nameList.add("Sam");
        nameList.add("Johnson");
        nameList.add("Hentry");
        nameList.add("Thamos");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.list_item, nameList);
        autoCompleteText.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }   
}
```

Comment: thank you jeba, but in your example you have to insert the words one by one. I need that the TextView is attached to the suggested words that Google will suggest.